# Fread function change name of first column in large csv files

Tags: r, csv

I have 2.3 GB `csv` file. When I read it using `fread` function present in data.table library of R , it adds a '`ï»¿`' symbol to the first column .

So my data's first column was '`HistoryID`' , after reading it through `fread` , it becomes '`ï»¿HistoryID`'. Other columns remain unaffected. 
Is there a specific encoding which should be used to solve this problem ?

When I read the data in `read.csv` function, this problem gets solved if we use ' UTF-8-BOM' encoding , but the same doesn't seem to work for `fread`.

Comment: edite question and add exmaple of input nad add your program

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation on cran -- [R-data.html#Variations-on-read_002etable](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/R-data.html#Variations-on-read_002etable)

Byte Order Marks still cause problem with encoding, and can be dealt with  like this:

```
it can be read on Windows by
read.table("intro.dat", fileEncoding = "UTF-8")

but on a Unix-alike might need
read.table("intro.dat", fileEncoding = "UTF-8-BOM")
```

Check the section `2.1 Variations on read.table`

It also seems to suggest that read.csv uses this trick.